# Jquery is not recognised after build from webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, laravel-5.4

So I am trying to do a build with `webpack` . And the compiled page is throwing error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object._typeof (bootstrap.js:30331)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js:27876)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js:70744)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap.js:20)
    at bootstrap.js:66
    at bootstrap.js:69
```

My Uncompiled

**`Bootstrap.js`**

```
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    window._ = require('lodash');


    window.Vue = require('vue');

    window.axios = require('axios');

    window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    };



    window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

    require('toastr');

    require('jquery-slimscroll');

    //Jquery sortable
    require('jquery-sortable');


    import "select2";
    import "./metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu";
    import "./dataTables/datatables.min";
    import "./datapicker/bootstrap-datepicker";
    import "./touchspin/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min";
    import "./inspinia";
```

After compiling I am getting that error in the browser , but I am not getting any compilation error

any one else got into similar problem ?

Thanks

Comment: you can try -import $ from 'jquery';

Comment: @MukulSharma sorry didn't get you , I am already assigning the Jquery to that variable na ?

Comment: I had a similar issue before. Probably some jquery plugin is not CommonJS compatible. Try to use the [`script-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader)

Comment: @Ematipico what should I do ?  even other plugins like toastr is also not working , $ , JQuery both are undefined

Comment: `require('script-loader!jquery')`

Comment: @Ematipico same error , I tried `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('script-loader!jquery');` and `require('script-loader!jquery');` both

Answer (score 0):

You have also to provide the scope to the context. Try to use the `ProvidePlugin`

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
 })
```

And don't delete the importing of your jQuery library

Comment: I tried that , Jquery error is gone but still , `$` is not definned